# Question about an algorithm

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

I got [this audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9080614) just now. It's a well written, detailed and properly explained question. But the question explicitly says that they know programming pretty well but they're asking for an algorithm for their problem.

That seems pretty clearly off topic to me so I flagged it, but I failed for doing that. I believe this is a faulty audit, but please correct me if I'm mistaken.

Comment: As a note: one of the comments even says to post it on Mathematics StackExchange which would mean that it would require flagging for a migration.

Comment: @Jamesking56 I strongly disagree with that. A question can be relevant on multiple stack exchange sites, but sometimes the asker might only find answers if he went to one of them, due to no fault of his own. Migration generally means the question is off-topic. The asker should just ask in that stack exchange as well. Also, there is no guarantee he would find answers there at all.

Answer (score 2):

The rules are not carved in stone. In general, an open question like this is "Too Broad" or "Primarily Opinion-Based", as everyone will give their own favorite resource.

However, sometimes an open question *can* be objectively answered. In this case, one of the commenters observes that it's really an instance of the Knapsack problem. This would be a great starting point for an answer, because although Knapsack itself is NP, there is a limited number of algorithms that can give sub-optimal results for such problems in reasonable time. One or more of these might fit the OP's needs. At any rate it shows that the OP has a non-trivial problem - and for which there is a limited number of good answers.

That being said, that audit is a bit of an edge case. Another request for an algorithm could easily fall in the "Too Broad" category.

Answer (score 1):

Questions about specific algorithms are generally great. It doesn't matter who the asker is, or how well he knows programming (this is always true, regarldess of the question). In fact, the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) gives *software algorithm* as an example of something you could ask about.

Those audit things are just there to kind of suggest what is okay on this site and what isn't (generally decided by consensus, I think).

Questions about mathematical algorithms are probably relevant both here and on Math StackExchange, and maybe on the other CS stack exchange sites as well, depending on the question.